# Error while deploying a contract on sepolia testnet with Brownie

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, evm, bitcoin-testnet

I'm currently trying to deploy a contract on sepolia testnets using Brownie and my Infura API, by running the following line of code:

```
brownie run scripts/my_contract.py --network sepolia
```

However, what I get is:

```
Running 'scripts\my_contract.py::main'...
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\my_contract.py", line 27, in main
    deploy_simple_storage()
  File ".\scripts\my_contract.py", line 7, in deploy_simple_storage
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 549, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 510, in deploy
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 720, in _make_transaction
    gas_price, gas_strategy, gas_iter = self._gas_price(gas_price)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 456, in _gas_price
    return web3.eth.generate_gas_price(), None, None
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 986, in generate_gas_price
    return self._generate_gas_price(transaction_params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 214, in _generate_gas_price
    return self.gasPriceStrategy(self.web3, transaction_params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\gas_strategies\rpc.py", line 20, in rpc_gas_price_strategy
    return web3.manager.request_blocking(RPC.eth_gasPrice, []) 
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 197, in request_blocking        
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 150, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware 
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py", line 90, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware 
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware   
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware 
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware 
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware 
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 40, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\exception_retry_request.py", line 105, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\providers\rpc.py", line 88, in make_request       
    raw_response = make_post_request(
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\request.py", line 113, in make_post_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\zanot\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status    
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/
```

It't relevant to note that everithing works if I use ganache.

I also want to say that running

```
brownie console --network sepolia
```

and

```
network.is_connected()
```

what I get is false.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: [Note that Brownie is no longer activately maintained. The recommendation is move to Ape](https://academy.apeworx.io/articles/porting-brownie-to-ape).